# How to handle python type hint for class method overrides

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, types, type-hinting

I want to give type hint for a class inheritance scenario:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")

class Mother(Generic[T, V]):
  def process(self, x: T) -> V:
    ...

class Child(Mother[int, str]):
  def process(self, x: int) -> str:
    ...
```

it feel like duplication because I need to provide the type hint twice (at the `class` line and below at the method definition line) - whereas I was hoping it could be inferred by python.
If I remove, let's say, the type hint in the method - then it seems that mypy is not capable of inferring it from the class type (weirdly though, if I provide an incompatible type hint, it is complaining).
Is there any way around that?

Comment: If you don't override `process` in `Child`, mypy infers the signature as `"def (x: builtins.int) -> builtins.str"`. Also, there are no mypy errors in your example, so it's hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: as a reader of your `Child` class, I'd want to see the type hints without having to work them out from your `Mother` class, so I'd say inferring them is _not_ ideal

Comment: @ringo yes there is no error - it was just about the missing inferrence. The thing though is I need to override its implementation (the mother is just a NotImplementedError) but not its type

Comment: @joel I understand why you would think that, I just feel it should be a developer choice? IDE can have inlay hints for example that make this available, without having the need to type it.